# How do I install and dual boot Windows 8 Pro alongside Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (installed first)?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS installed on my Acer E5-473G-399E machine with a non formatted 1 Terabyte HDD.

How do I install and dual boot Windows 8 Pro alongside Ubuntu 16.04LTS, (I already installed Ubuntu first)?

Answer (score -1):

I have made the same mistake. I decided to stop making things harder and went with the [Super Grub2 Disk](https://sourceforge.net/projects/supergrub2/) boot disk/usb/cd.

I was dutifully ashamed of myself for not effectively solving in by the terminal but got over it. :)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to use this to achieve OP's aim. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)